# if statement not working after deploy source code to ubuntu - python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on a python project and facing an issue, I have a snippet of code like bellow:

```
if published_to is not '*':
    if 'T00:00:00.000Z' not in published_to:
        published_to = published_to.replace('T00:00:00.000Z', '')
        published_to = published_to.split('-')[::-1]
        published_to = '-'.join(published_to) + 'T00:00:00.000Z'
```

And, the above code running like charm when I run my server on windows with python 2.7, but when I deploy the project to Ubuntu 16.04 with the same version of python it's running through the body of "if" statement no mater `published_to` equal to `*` or not. So, could anyone please tell me the reason???

Comment: Can you show that code that sets `published_to`? It appears that is getting a different answer on the two servers.

Comment: Have you verified exactly what `published_to` contains?

Comment: My first suspicion is a difference in how time is stored on Windows vs non-Windows systems.  Windows changes the hardware clock to whatever local time is.  Every other system changes the hardware clock to UTC, and translates as appropriate to local time.  A place to check, after you've verified what `published_to` contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check whether `published_to` is *equal to* `'*'` or not, then use `!=`:

```
if published_to != '*':
```

Using `is not` checks *object identity*, which is a stronger test than equality and not what you are looking for here. (Basically, you can have two different string objects that contain the same text - different objects, but they're *equal*).

Comment: Thank you, that's working, but why "is not" statement running on windows but Ubuntu?

Comment: @user2905416: I couldn't say why you can see a difference in behaviour between the two systems, but it could be due to either a different minor version of Python or a difference in Python implementation between the systems. Whether a particular Python implementation on a particular system interns strings or not is considered an implementation detail.